# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clang_rt.asan_static_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, llvm

I'm building the software [Vengi Voxel](https://github.com/vengi-voxel/vengi) and it works perfectly fine on Ubuntu App running on Windows 11. But now I'm trying to directly build it on *Windows 11* using the console `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022` that comes with the [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) and I figured out the steps:

> - Install `CMake` from https://cmake.org/download/
> - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > type `sysdm.cpl` > Advanced > Environment Variables...
> - Click <kbd>New</kbd> and add path: `C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin`
> - Download `ninja.exe` from https://ninja-build.org/
> - Add `ninja.exe` to PATH or if you're lazy paste it into `C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin`
> - Install *VSCode* from https://code.visualstudio.com/
> - Download *Visual Studio Community* from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/
> - You need to add at least 1 Workload before installation: *MSVC*
> - Navigate find the C/C++ compiler `cl.exe` somehwere in `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/<year>/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/<version>/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe`
>   and copy this path
> - Example: `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe`
> - Copy the path in the folder address bar and add 3 more environment variables `CC` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` with this
>   path value.
> - Open Visual Studio Community > Skip Sign-In > Skip this for Now
> - Restart computer
> - Windows > Search > "x64" > open: `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022`
> - cd to the `vengi` folder and make sure you delete the `build` folder
> - Type `make` to configure and build

But I run into a problem maybe related to [this bug ticket](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/8891), but I don't understand what exactly was done to resolve their problem. This is the fatal error output:

```
D:\projects\vox\vengi>make
[7/694] Linking CXX executable binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.exe
FAILED: binary_to_compressed_c/vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.exe
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests tools\binary_to_compressed_c\application.manifest -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir\binary_to_compressed_c.cpp.obj tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir\application.rc.res  /out:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.exe /implib:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.lib /pdb:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /MANIFEST:NO /STACK:5000000 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib winmm.lib imm32.lib comctl32.lib version.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib winhttp.lib dbghelp.lib wsock32.lib ws2_32.lib iphlpapi.lib rpcrt4.lib wininet.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir\binary_to_compressed_c.cpp.obj tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir\application.rc.res /out:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.exe /implib:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.lib /pdb:binary_to_compressed_c\vengi-binary_to_compressed_c.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /MANIFEST:NO /STACK:5000000 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib winmm.lib imm32.lib comctl32.lib version.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib winhttp.lib dbghelp.lib wsock32.lib ws2_32.lib iphlpapi.lib rpcrt4.lib wininet.lib tools\binary_to_compressed_c\CMakeFiles\binary_to_compressed_c.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
LINK : warning LNK4300: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' because input module contains ASAN metadata
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clang_rt.asan_static_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib'
[16/694] Building CXX object src\modules\core\CMakeFiles\tests-core.dir\tests\ConcurrentPriorityQueueTest.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I read that `clang_rt.asan_static_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib` is supposed to be part of the clang/LLVM installation, but upon further research I could not find this library. I did find `clang_rt.asan_static-x86_64.lib` within the `C:\Program Files\LLVM` directory but they are different I suppose. Where can I get the `clang_rt.asan_static_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the workload `C++ AddressSanitizer`. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/

[image]

Comment: Or turn it off `-DUSE_SANITIZERS=OFF`

Comment: Hi,@Harry McKenzie. Is your problem sovled? If so, you could mark it so that it can help more people.

Comment: yes thanks for the reminder. i marked it as closed. it's specifically -`DUSE_SANITIZERS=OFF` that solved it for me but for those who still want to use sanitizer, it didn't completely solve the problem yet as the linking phase would still not work properly to get a stand-alone exe file.